# how to user Rectangle

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to user Rectangle to display two colors in VS 2010 window phone, if Rectangle can't, please tell how to do.

```
<Rectangle Height="20" Width="400" Stroke="White" Fill="Green" StrokeThickness="1">
```

Comment: I suggest you to google before asking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its possible through a gradient. but otherwise i would suggest to do two rectangles, so both just have the half of the height/width (depending on where you want do have the colors)